# get_the_terms error

Tags: taxonomy, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm using the [CPT-onomies plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-onomies/) to make a CPT into a taxonomy. I have a hero image CPT (created with *CPT-onomies*) and the hero images post type is attached to the page post type. This allows me to select a hero image post that will be a term of a page post. All of this is working fine. When I visit the page with the hero image as a taxonomy the hero image appears as desired.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that if I'm on a page whose ancestor has a hero image attached, I want the page to show the hero image attached to the parent.  Below is my code. I get an array of ancestors and iterate through the array. The image shows up as desired but above the image this error appears:

> **Notice: Undefined property**: `stdClass::$data` in `.../wp-includes/category-template.php` on *line 1176*

```
//Get the current Post ID
$current_post_id = get_the_id();

//Get the current Post's ancestor's ID's
$current_post_parents = get_ancestors($current_post_id, 'page');


foreach ( $current_post_parents as $post_parent ) {

      //If a hero image ID is associated with the current post being viewed (or a parent post of the current post) assign that hero image ID value to $hero_image_id
      $hero_image_id = isset( $post_parent ) && ( $assigned_hero_images = get_the_terms( $post_parent, 'hero_images' ) ) && is_array( $assigned_hero_images ) && ( $hero_image = array_shift( $assigned_hero_images ) ) && isset( $hero_image->term_id ) ? $hero_image->term_id : NULL;

      if ($hero_image_id)
         break;

} //Code follows that displays the image based on the $hero_image_id
```

It's the `get_the_terms()` function that's throwing the error. Line 1176 of the `category-template.php` file is `$to_cache[ $key ] = $term->data;`

To be clear, the notice only appears when I'm visiting a child page whose ancestor has a hero image attached. If I'm visiting the page on which the hero image is attached or visiting a page with no hero image attached on the page or any ancestor page then no error appears.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `wp_get_object_terms()` function instead of `get_the_terms()`. The `get_the_terms()` function attempts to cache the terms where `wp_get_object_terms()` does not.

The fixed code to get the hero images CPT's ID is:

```
$hero_image_id = ( $assigned_hero_images = wp_get_object_terms( $post_parent, 'hero_images' ) ) && ( $hero_image = array_shift( $assigned_hero_images ) ) && isset( $hero_image->term_id ) ? $hero_image->term_id : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with this line:

`$hero_image_id = isset( $post_parent ) && ( $assigned_hero_images = get_the_terms( $post_parent, 'hero_images' ) ) && is_array( $assigned_hero_images ) && ( $hero_image = array_shift( $assigned_hero_images ) ) && isset( $hero_image->term_id ) ? $hero_image->term_id : NULL;`

I think I see what you're going for, but PHP is not processing it in the order you think it is.

Let me try to break this down:

```
isset( $post_parent ) // This isn't necessary since it couldn't not exist and still get into this code block.

$assigned_hero_images = get_the_terms( $post_parent, 'hero_images' )

is_array( $assigned_hero_images ) // again, you just created it, so you don't need to check here.

$hero_image = array_shift( $assigned_hero_images )  // You're trying to access the contents of the first element of the array, but this isn't the best approach.

$hero_image->term_id
```

A cleaned up version that accomplishes what you're doing above would look like this:

```
$hero_image_id = get_the_terms( $post_parent, 'hero_images')[0]->$term_id;
```

The `[0]` gets you access to the first array element, and `->$term_id` gets that property from the object. You can do this without saving each to a variable by a process in php called [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

This is not tested so I may have missed something, but hopefully it gets you in the ballpark enough to troubleshoot it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really appreciate it! I made some of the changes that you suggested. Unfortunately, this solution didn't work for me because in the WP core code the get_the_terms() function attempts to cache the terms. I posted the answer below.